# How can the QListView support gesture sliding?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

In Qt, I try to pass through `QScroller::grabGesture(ui->listView, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);`The code sets the scrolling function of the QListView, but it doesn't actually work. Instead, it supports it in the QListWidget.

Note: I use Qt widgets, not QML.

QListView invalid.gif

[image]

QListWidget effect.gif

[image]

Comment: You could try attaching the `QScroller` to the viewport with `QScroller::grabGesture(ui->listView->viewport(), ...`.

Comment: I tried "QScroller::grabGesture(ui->listView->viewport(), ..." again and still couldn't swipe in the QListView, but I could swipe in the QListWidget.